# Adding new user Tab in the doxygen Layout

Tags: doxygen, doxywizard

I am new to using doxygen 1.8.7. I am trying to add the Architecture diagram to be the part of the API documentation generated for my C# project using doxygen. I generated the default doxygen Layout file (DoxygenLayout.xml) and edited it by adding the below changes -

```
<navindex>
    <tab type="mainpage" visible="yes" title="">
        <tab type="mainpage" visible="yes" title="Audience" />
        <tab type="user" url="@ref Architecture" title="My Page" />
    </tab>
    <tab type="pages" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
    <tab type="modules" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
    <tab type="namespaces" visible="yes" title="">
      <tab type="namespacelist" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
      <tab type="namespacemembers" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
    </tab>
    <tab type="classes" visible="yes" title="">
      <tab type="classlist" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
      <tab type="classindex" visible="$ALPHABETICAL_INDEX" title=""/> 
      <tab type="hierarchy" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
      <tab type="classmembers" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
    </tab>
    <tab type="files" visible="yes" title="">
      <tab type="filelist" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
      <tab type="globals" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
    </tab>
    <tab type="examples" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>  

  </navindex>
```

The Architecture diagram is an external document and is not generated by running doxygen.
So my question is -
Where do I put this Architecture Document?? Or should it be a part of the project solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple to accomplish. You've already done the hard part by generating the custom `DoxygenLayout.xml` file. Now, you just need to add a custom tab to it:

```xml
<tab type="user" url="architecture.html" title="Architecture"/>
```

You can put that wherever you want under the `<navindex>` tag. For testing purposes, you can just toss it in at the very end of the group.

The `title` attribute can be any text string that you want.

The `url` attribute can be a URL to any file you want. It doesn't have to be an HTML file, of course. It can be a PDF, Word DOC, or whatever. You can also use `"@ref mypage"` to link to a doxygen page named `mypage` ([see the documentation for details](http://www.doxygen.org/manual/commands.html#cmdref)).

Answer (score 0):

Using the following command generates the default *DoxygenLayout.xml* document:

```
doxygen -l
```

The next step is to mention the layout file in the configuration file:

**LAYOUT_FILE = DoxygenLayout.xml**

Doxygen GUI 1.8.20

[image]

Comment: Would be nice to mention the version of the doxywizard you used (you are using a bit an older version though won't make a real difference for your anwer). It would also be nice to see to it that in the help part (bottom left) the information about `LAYOUT_FILE` is present and not about one of the other settings.