# Doxygen: Customizing the Examples Page

Tags: doxygen

While documenting a project with Doxygen, I encountered the following problem.

I have a set of example programs (demo_1.c, demo_2.c,...) which reside inside the `EXAMPLE_PATH` set in the *Doxyfile*. I created a file `examples.c` with the following content to include the examples:

```
/**
 * \example demo_1.c 
 * \example demo_2.c 
 * ...
 */
```

After running Doxygen, an Examples page is created within the navigation as I want it but the Examples section always looks like:

```
Examples 
--------
Here is a list of all examples:
 * demo_1.c
 * demo_2.c
```

How can I change this page? I especially want to replace the text "Here is a list of all examples:" with a larger introduction.

I already generated the doxygen layout file and the header/footer files but this does not give me any useful information.

Comment: I have this issue too. It is actually easier/better to create a Markdown file than using the built-in example listing support.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create a [DoxygenLayout.xml](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html#layout) file and customize it with the information you want to appear on the examples page.

Doxygen will produce a template XML file, in the current directory, from the configuration it is using currently via the following command line:

```
$ doxygen -l
```

Point Doxygen to this file by editing the `Doxyfile` configuration file or using the Doxywizard GUI (Expert tab -> Build -> LAYOUT_FILE) to change the `LAYOUT_FILE` path to your new `DoxygenLayout.xml` file.

I recommend doing this step explicitly instead of relying on the default behavior to pickup the `DoxygenLayout.xml` when it exists in the folder Doxygen is run from.

You will need to edit the `<tab type="examples">` XML tag and change the existing `title` attribute and add an `intro` attribute to suit your needs. The `title` attribute changes both the name of the header on the page and the TAB name across the top of the HTML browser so something shorter is better.

For example:

```
   <tab type="examples" visible="yes" title="ALI Library Examples" intro="Welcome to the fantastic set of examples I have prepared for your enjoyment."/>
```

Produces:

> ## ALI Library Examples
>
> Welcome to the fantastic set of examples I have prepared for your enjoyment.
>
> - csv-simple.tcl

Note that I could not find any information about the `intro` attribute in the formal Doxygen documentation. I noticed it while reading the article [Adding new user Tab in the Doxygen Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417671/adding-new-user-tab-in-the-doxygen-layout).