# How to combine a wiki page into doxygen output

Tags: markdown, doxygen, wiki

I have a URI to a wiki page that I want to combine with my doxygen output.

1. How should I should modify my Doxyfile to pull in the wiki's markdown file?
2. How can I give the URI to the wiki to my Doxyfile, so that I do not have to maintain a repo-level copy of it for doxygen to use?

To clarify further, I have GitHub wiki page (markdown file) for my project that I want to have rendered into doxygen html output.  What is the procedure for doing this?

FYI: Here is what I tried:

- I created a separate tab in my layout with a link to the wiki as a temporary workaround ("[Adding new user Tab in the doxygen Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417671/adding-new-user-tab-in-the-doxygen-layout)"), but I will need to render the wiki into my html doxygen output, for delivery to our customer.
- Copied over the wiki's markdown file to my repo, added the file's path to my Doxyfile's `INPUT`, however all of the internal page links from the (GitHub) markdown do not work (tried with three different browsers).  Here is how the internal links look

`[fnReadValue](#fnReadValue)`

Comment: 1) do you have the markdown locally or on a https(s)? have a look at the INPUT tag 2) not 100% clear what you mean but maybe just use the http(s) address of the md page?

Comment: Please see my clarification in the question

Comment: How do these internal page links look like? There have been some problems with links to `.md` file but this is resolved in the master version (see: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/6913). When you want to see your markdown files in the doxygen output you need to add them all to the doxygen input so doxygen can convert them (unless they are links to the outside, then the outside renderer is responsible).To see what your problem is it would be usefull to see coe that signals the problem.

Comment: Have added format of the internal links to the question

Comment: Some more information, a complete MWE would be useful still very unclear what is wheer.